# Copying Formula for Microsoft Excel by drag and drop

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to understand how to gain more control when I drag a formula to other cells.

The problem I have is:

I have a formula that is `"=SUM(Assumptions!C12:D28)"`, which I'd like to drag several times in the same row so that I have `"Sum(Assumptions!C12:E28)"`, `"Sum(Assumptions!C12:F28)"`, etc.

When I mark the first formula and drag it to the right in my row I instead get `"=Sum(Assumptions!D12:E28)"` and `"=Sum(Assumptions!E12:F28)"`, etc.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get first value of your formula locked, just put`$` in front of range or select `C12` and press `F4` until you get `$C12`. Then your formula looks like that:

```
=SUM(Assumptions!$C12:D28)
```

`$` sign in front of row index and column index means, if you fill handle or copy paste your formula, row or column index will not change. For example:

`$C$12` - Column C and row 12 never change if you copy paste formula;

`$C12` - Column C never change if you copy paste formula;

`C$12` - Row 12 never change if you copy paste formula.

Comment: Read this article also: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hub/2011/04/26/formula-watch-lock-excel-formulas-so-they-dont-change-when-you-paste/

Comment: Works perfectly well! Thank you very much!!

Comment: I just did it. Thanks